# What is the best way to read settings for UI Xamarin test from json file with DI?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, autofac, ui-testing, xamarin.uitest

I have a few tests which read data out of config.json file for determining the test details of each platform.

They look like this

```html
{
    "Devices" :  {
        "Settings": [
            {
                "Platform": "iOS",
                "SerialNumbers": [
                    "b509b42b821a0b2eeb58ed5659e504c118d0323c"
                ],
                "AssemblyPath": "realbundlename"
            },
            {
                "Platform": "Android",
                "SerialNumbers": [
                    "ZX1G22VMH7"
                ],
                "AssemblyPath": "../../../Droid/bin/Release/nameoffile.apk"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The question is how to read data from json in UI Test App project.

I try to use Autofac and read data with module functionality, but when I debug I got that data not read from the file. I guess the problem with the type of project.

I try to develop it as in [this](http://piotrgankiewicz.com/2016/06/06/storing-c-app-settings-with-json/) article.

Does anyone know what the best way to do this is?
Or maybe someone has better idea how to read data from .json?

Answer (score 0):

Use System.IO to read it from disk, and then use Json.Net to deserialize it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Yep, I know it, thanks!
But I'd like to use DI. I guess it better solution. 
What do you think about it?

Comment: But even if you use DI you need some implementation behind it, DI makes it easy to easily change implementation.